# Rsync issue: dowload folder from remote server to local server

Tags: linux, rsync

I have an issue with rsync on centOS. 
My command is: rsync -ravz --progress root@myipaddress:/var/www/website/ .
Following my error:

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
receiving incremental file list
./
.htaccess
          31 100%   30.27kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=996/998)
flush.php
        2681 100%    2.56MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=995/998)
resource_config.json
         206 100%  201.17kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=994/998)
cache/
```

**I'm download folder from debian server.**
After 4 seconds rsync was in "standby". Why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm, I'm wondering if that missing terminal variable is messing things up. Try running this first, then your rsync:

```
export TERM='linux'
```

Comment: Did the error message go away? And just double check that you have the same version of RSync on both machines?

Comment: I have same version on both. I believe there's a network problem.. maybe. Thanks again for reply.